# Visual studio Community 2017 Xamarin cannot compile my program IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

hello everyone i have problems with compiling and running a program that i wrote::

i have written a very simple hello world program in Xamarini visual studio 2017 the error says::,

before runnning the aplication you have to be conected to the compiler servers Or something like that (my visual studio is not english)
I am tryin to run the app in my iphone 5 phone

Comment: You cannot compile an iOS app without having an Apple Mac machine.

Comment: in order to build an iOS app from Visual Studio (on a PC) you must have a Mac to act as a build server

Comment: oh i dont have a mac what can i do

Comment: Buy one! Or use a cloud based service to build it?

Comment: If you don't have a Mac, and you must have a Mac to compile for iOS, you have two options: acquire a Mac, or don't compile for iOS.

Comment: how can i do it without a MAC

Comment: As we've said several times, **you can't**.

Answer (score 0):

You can only build iOS apps using a Mac machine.  As the other comments say, you would need to buy or borrow a Mac to run the build on or you can use cloud based rental services (search google for 'Mac in the cloud' for examples)

If what you are really asking is how can I build for iOS without spending money - the answer is that you can't.